# Multiple seek bar

Tags: android

I have implemented multiple seek bar in android like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sb1=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    sb2=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    sb3=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);

    tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    sb2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    sb3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) 
{

    switch (arg0.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.seekBar1:
        tv1.setText(arg1);
        break;
    case R.id.seekBar2:
        tv2.setText(arg1);
        break;
    case R.id.seekBar3:
        tv3.setText(arg1);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Whenever I run this app, it gives the following errors:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:String resource ID #0x1
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at com.example.allocationseekbar.MainActivity.onProgressChanged(MainActivity.java:42)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.widget.SeekBar.onProgressRefresh(SeekBar.java:89)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.doRefreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:506)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.refreshProgress(ProgressBar.java:515)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.widget.ProgressBar.setProgress(ProgressBar.java:564)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.trackTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:337)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.onTouchEvent(AbsSeekBar.java:292)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1671)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1655)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-18 15:41:13.200: E/AndroidRuntime(596):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know why this is happening. Please help me. Thanxs in advance

Comment: Thanks Samir for editing this. May I know how you have changed logcat error in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an `int` into the `setText()` method of your `TextView` which is the overload to look for a resource with that ID.  You need to change it (and the similar lines) to:

```
tv1.setText(arg1.toString());
```

Comment: We have to cast integer to string: use  tv1.setText(Integer.toString(arg1)) or tv1.setText(""+arg1)

Comment: Or my way which is normally the preferred way...

Answer (score 0):

We can use following for the solution:

```
 1. tv1.setText(Integer.toString(arg1))
 2. tv1.setText(""+arg1)
```